# Camunda Process Engine configuration with MockExpressionManager for wildfly

Tags: java, wildfly, wildfly-8, jboss-arquillian, camunda

We have Camunda installed as a module for Wildfly8.
Everything works fine, but I need a way to mock java delegates for unit tests (with Arquillian).
As I understand, org.camunda.bpm.engine.test.mock.Mocks can be used to provide mocked delegates.
According to JavaDoc, I should register MockExpressionManager in my process engine configuration.
I've found some similar config with MockExpressingManager here
https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-assert/blob/master/camunda-bpm-assert-examples/src/test/resources/camunda.cfg.xml

but camunda module for wildfly is configured in standalone-full.xml:

```
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:org.camunda.bpm.jboss:1.1">
        <process-engines>
            <process-engine name="default" default="true">
                <datasource>
                    java:jboss/datasources/ProcessEngine
                </datasource>
                <history-level>
                    full
                </history-level>
                <configuration>
                    org.camunda.bpm.engine.cdi.CdiJtaProcessEngineConfiguration
                </configuration>
                <properties>
                    <property name="jobExecutorAcquisitionName">
                        default
                    </property>
                    <property name="isAutoSchemaUpdate">
                        true
                    </property>
                    <property name="authorizationEnabled">
                        true
                    </property>
                    <property name="jobExecutorDeploymentAware">
                        true
                    </property>
                    <property name="expressionManager">
                        org.camunda.bpm.engine.test.mock.MockExpressionManager
                    </property>                     
                </properties>
```

but this doesn't work, and on wildfly startup I see

```
16:45:31,930 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) MSC000001: Failed to start service org.camunda.bpm.platform.process-engine.default: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service org.camunda.bpm.platform.process-engine.default: org.camunda.bpm.engine.ProcessEngineException: Could not set value for property 'expressionManager' on class org.camunda.bpm.engine.cdi.CdiJtaProcessEngineConfiguration
    at org.camunda.bpm.container.impl.jboss.service.MscManagedProcessEngineController$1.run(MscManagedProcessEngineController.java:97)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [rt.jar:1.8.0_11]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [rt.jar:1.8.0_11]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_11]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_11]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_11]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122) [jboss-threads-2.1.1.Final.jar:2.1.1.Final]
Caused by: org.camunda.bpm.engine.ProcessEngineException: Could not set value for property 'expressionManager' on class org.camunda.bpm.engine.cdi.CdiJtaProcessEngineConfiguration
    at org.camunda.bpm.container.impl.metadata.PropertyHelper.applyProperty(PropertyHelper.java:76)
    at org.camunda.bpm.container.impl.metadata.PropertyHelper.applyProperties(PropertyHelper.java:94)
    at org.camunda.bpm.container.impl.jboss.service.MscManagedProcessEngineController.startProcessEngine(MscManagedProcessEngineController.java:173)
    at org.camunda.bpm.container.impl.jboss.service.MscManagedProcessEngineController$2.run(MscManagedProcessEngineController.java:131)
    at org.camunda.bpm.container.impl.jboss.service.MscManagedProcessEngineController$2.run(MscManagedProcessEngineController.java:129)
    at org.camunda.bpm.container.impl.jboss.util.Tccl.runWithTccl(Tccl.java:53)
    at org.camunda.bpm.container.impl.jboss.util.Tccl.runUnderClassloader(Tccl.java:45)
    at org.camunda.bpm.container.impl.jboss.service.MscManagedProcessEngineController.startInternal(MscManagedProcessEngineController.java:129)
    at org.camunda.bpm.container.impl.jboss.service.MscManagedProcessEngineController$1.run(MscManagedProcessEngineController.java:90)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_11]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_11]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_11]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) [rt.jar:1.8.0_11]
    at org.camunda.bpm.container.impl.metadata.PropertyHelper.applyProperty(PropertyHelper.java:74)
    ... 14 more
```

How to set this MockExpressionManager to the configuration correctly?

Or may be there are some other ways to mock java delegates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From looking at the Camunda code, they're expecting a reference to an expression manager to be passed in.  If I had to guess, this is being passed in as a string.  A dirty way I can think of to handle this is to create your subclass of `CdiJtaProcessEngineConfiguration` which configures the proper expression manager, deploy that JAR to their module and wire that in.

Personally, I found their configuration to be a bit too tight for me in direct wildfly integration and chose to configure their library in my app directly.

Comment: Also, I've noticed this in the CdiJtaProcessEngineConfiguration:
  protected void initExpressionManager() {
    expressionManager = new CdiExpressionManager();    
  } and it looks like it always create CdiExpressionManager, without checking expressionManager for null. Probably if a pass the MockExpressionManager, it will not work...

Comment: Hence why I recommended that you subclass and override the behavior.